# How to specify free text input in a dashboard in Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I would like to set up a dashboard to display information about a customer.

To do so, the user will need to input an ID which identifies the customer.

I know how to set up custom filters, but those don't seem to allow free text entry.

How do I set up a dashboard that allows a user to input some text which is then used in a query in the underlying worksheet.

Answer (score 3):

Can't be done yet, maybe add it to Snowflake Suggestions in the community page?

Comment: Thanks. Is there any work-around for a use case like this ? I could share a worksheet and have the user edit the WHERE clause to change `WHERE pID = 12345"  to whatever pID they choose, but that hardly seems like a good alternative.

Comment: Yea i think for now that is the path to take, you can set a SQL variable at the top of the page to edit so the variable can be used everywhere in your session code

Answer (score 0):

Snowflake does not currently support this funtionality.

A workaround is to use a BI tool such as Power BI as a front end.

Alternatively you could roll-your-own using something like R Shiny.